# can i run emulator for android studio without enabling Virtualization technology

Tags: android

I haven't a license to change my PC BIOS settings to enable the VT-x for emulating my work.
IS Genymotion can solve the problem without enabling Virtual devices in BIOS settings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, older were able to virtual machines without VT-x support so it is a high possibility that you can run an emulator without VT-x support. Select ARM architecture while creating the virtual machine and you are done.